# Excel Powerquery split table top / bottom 50 percent

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have an example table in Excel to illustrate my question.
Two columns (first name, last name), 11 rows and a header row.
I would like to make get&transform (powerquery) links to another sheet in the same workbook where I would like to have two tables A & B with the same structure als the source table. I would like A to display row 1-6 and B to display 7-11.

BUT: I would like this split to be dynamic. So I would want A to display Top 50% rounded up, and B to display the rest. I've seen the top N rows and read some posts about counting in a different powerquery and using this [Filedropper Excel file where image below comes from](http://www.filedropper.com/examplefileexcelpowerquerysplittable)

[image: I've attached the file to get an idea of what I want.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top Half:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTable"]}[Content],
    TopHalfRows = Number.RoundUp(Table.RowCount(Source) / 2),
    KeepTopHalf = Table.FirstN(Source, TopHalfRows)
in
    KeepTopHalf
```

Bottom Half:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTable"]}[Content],
    TopHalfRows = Number.RoundUp(Table.RowCount(Source) / 2),
    DeleteTopHalf = Table.Skip(Source, TopHalfRows)
in
    DeleteTopHalf
```

**EDIT:**

This shows how to amend by adding a filter step, before splitting:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([firstname], "Ab")),
    TopHalfRows = Number.RoundUp(Table.RowCount(#"Filtered Rows") / 2),
    KeepTopHalf = Table.FirstN(#"Filtered Rows", TopHalfRows)
in
    KeepTopHalf
```

Comment: This is great! I have a follow up question. Could I add a filter to:
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTable"]}[Content],
For instance, only using firstnames starting with 'ab' ?

Comment: I'm not sure how. I want to filter before the count. So it has to filter the SourceTable .

Comment: Insert the filter step after the Source step, then reference that filter step instead of Source in the following rows.

Comment: I've edited answer to show an example of applying a filter before splitting.

Comment: Found it Olly, Thank you so much. I've added a line between, filtering the source, using that filtered result. Great stuff. Much appreciated!